# cURL call in C# with flag

Tags: c#, .net, curl, solr

I'd like to make a following curl call in C#:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true" -F "myfile=@tutorial.html"
```

I found that I should use WebRequest class, but I'm still not sure how deal with this part:

```
-F "myfile=@tutorial.html"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code snippet from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx shows how to send POST data using the WebRequest class:

```
// Create a request using a URL that can receive a post. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true");
// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";
// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = "myfile=@tutorial.html";
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to WebRequest, you might consider using the WebClient class. It offers what might be considered to be a cleaner and simpler syntax than WebRequest. Something like this:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            byte[] postResult = client.UploadFile("http://localhost:8983/solr/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true", "POST", "tutorial.html");
        }
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/esst63h0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx